# VBA function issues

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a project where I need to analyse availability of staff based on 15-minute time periods, their language skills and their shifts. I have one sheet that looks like this:

```
--Time-------English------German-----French

--06:15--------0------------0-----------0
--06:30--------0------------0-----------0
--06:45--------0------------0-----------0
```

And another one that looks like this:

```
--Name-----Language-----Info--------Shift--------

--Joe B----English-----BlaBla---05:45 - 12:30---
--Al C-----English-----BlaBla---07:45 - 15:30---
--Jill T---English-----BlaBla---07:45 - 15:30---
```

So, I need to take the Language they speak, their shift (split into start and end times) and based on the language specified in the heading of that column (in the first sheet given above) add '1' if they speak that language and are available at that time.

Below is the code I have at present which is not doing this for me:

```
Function CalculateAvailability(The_Time As String, The_Info As Range, Current_Lang As String)

'The_Time is the current 15-minute period
'The_Info is the range of fields in sheet 2 with our information (A3:D5 above)
'Current_Lang is the current language heading

Dim The_Lang As String 'the language of the staff member
Dim The_Shift_Start As String 'obvious
Dim The_Shift_End As String 'also obvious
Dim stGotIt As String 'redundant, not used currently
Dim stCell As String 'for capturing the cell contents
Dim Counter As Integer 'our counter

Counter = 0

For Each r In The_Info.Rows
    For Each c In r.Cells
        stCell = c.Value
        If InStr(1, stCell, ":", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            The_Shift_Start = GetShiftStart(stCell) 'this code works
            The_Shift_End = GetShiftEnd(stCell) 'this code works
        End If
        If InStr(1, stCell, Current_Lang, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            The_Lang = Current_Lang 'seems redundant but how else to do the check?
            Counter = 17 'test value - doesn't seem to reach here
        End If
    Next c
    If The_Lang = Current_Lang Then
        Counter = 5 'test value - doesn't seem to reach here either
    End If
Next r

CalculateAvailability = "Time:" + The_Time + " - Start:" + The_Shift_Start + " - End:" + The_Shift_End + " - Avail. " + Counter 'for output purposes

End Function
```

It doesn't seem to be reaching the important parts of my code where I would do the calculation that calls a seperate (tested and working) function that returns '1' or '0' based on the time period and the shift start and end times. (That would be where I specify Counter = 5) Is my logic in the code above incorrect? I realise that the testing of the language seems redundant and is probably incorrect, but as the commenting says, I couldn't rework that more sensibly. One thing I'm curious about is does the For Loop immediately jump from the "Next" back to the related "For Each" or does it carry out the following code and THEN jump back up? (I know this wouldn't make much sense programmatically, but I'm not that familiar with VB so I can't say for sure, despite how ridiculous it seems in light of my C/C#/C++ knowledge)

All help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you run it in Step Mode in the Debugger??

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `Current_Lang` is not sent in as an empty string and the code never reaches the line `Counter = 17`, it will never reach the line `Counter = 5` either, so I think you can concentrate on why it doesn't reach `Counter = 17`.

The most likely answer to that would seem to be that `stCell` does not contain what you expect it to contain and so this is the reason why it can't find `Current_Lang` in there. Try to output or `Watch` what's in `stCell` so you can check why it's not working.

Comment: And, of course, it was something ridiculously obvious and tiny. InStr(1, stCell, Current_Lang, vbTextCompare) >= 0 - I had not initially included the >= and so it was returning 0 as that was the index of the first character in the checked for string. Thanks for the response though, it helped to focus the issue!

Comment: @Darragh If @ho1 helped to solve your issue, perhaps you may upvote his answer, and even accept it. Read the faqs!